# Mapsforge using DownlaodLayer for OpenCycleMap

Tags: rendering, openstreetmap, tile, mapsforge

I would like to ask if there is any difference between rendering online tile and offline map.

I have the following code, it runs successfully when I use tile render layer from a offline map.
However, it doesn't work if i use tileDownloadLayer.

Below is the code it doesn't work. Only grey layer displayed instead of map tile using tileDownloadLayer.

```
    private static final String MAP_FILE = "hongkong_cycle.map";  // name of the map file in the external storage
    private static MapDataStore mapDataStore = new MapFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("lab.geospatial.maps").toString() + "/" + MAP_FILE);
    private MapView mapView;
    private TileRendererLayer tileRendererLayer;
    private TileCache tileCache;
    private Layer sketchLayer;
    private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
    private LatLong MY_INIT_ZOOM_CENTER = new LatLong(22.305, 114.1793);
    private byte MY_INIT_ZOOM_LEVEL = 13;
    private LatLong currentHotSpot = MY_INIT_ZOOM_CENTER;
    private TappableMarker positionMarker;
    private String inputGeo;
    private boolean enableLongPressInfo = false;
    private boolean enableSketch = false;
    private PaintView paintView;
    public View rootView;
    protected TileDownloadLayer downloadLayer;



protected void createMapViews() {
    mapView = getMapView();
    findViewById(R.id.rotateView).setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mapView.getModel().frameBufferModel.setOverdrawFactor(1.0d);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.getMapScaleBar().setVisible(false);
    mapView.getModel().displayModel.setFixedTileSize(256);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mapView.setZoomLevelMin((byte) 10);
    mapView.setZoomLevelMax((byte) 18);

    // create a tile cache of suitable size
    tileCache = AndroidUtil.createTileCache(this, "mapcache", mapView.getModel().displayModel.getTileSize(), 1f, mapView.getModel().frameBufferModel.getOverdrawFactor());

    OnlineTileSource onlineTileSource = new OnlineTileSource(new String[]{
            "a.tile.thunderforest.com", "b.tile.thunderforest.com", "c.tile.thunderforest.com"},
            80);
    onlineTileSource.setName("openCycle").setAlpha(false)
            .setBaseUrl("/cycle/")
            .setParallelRequestsLimit(8).setProtocol("http").setTileSize(256)
            .setZoomLevelMax((byte) 25).setZoomLevelMin((byte) 0);
    onlineTileSource.setUserAgent("Mapsforge Samples");

    downloadLayer = new TileDownloadLayer(tileCache,
            mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition, onlineTileSource,
            AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE);

    mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(downloadLayer);

    mapView.setCenter(MY_INIT_ZOOM_CENTER);
    mapView.setZoomLevel(MY_INIT_ZOOM_LEVEL);


}
```

However, if I use tileRenderLayer with sample offline map, it works fine with map displayed successfully.

```
    private static final String MAP_FILE = "hongkong_cycle.map";  // name of the map file in the external storage
    private static MapDataStore mapDataStore = new MapFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("lab.geospatial.maps").toString() + "/" + MAP_FILE);
    private MapView mapView;
    private TileRendererLayer tileRendererLayer;
    private TileCache tileCache;
    private Layer sketchLayer;
    private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
    private LatLong MY_INIT_ZOOM_CENTER = new LatLong(22.305, 114.1793);
    private byte MY_INIT_ZOOM_LEVEL = 13;
    private LatLong currentHotSpot = MY_INIT_ZOOM_CENTER;
    private TappableMarker positionMarker;
    private String inputGeo;
    private boolean enableLongPressInfo = false;
    private boolean enableSketch = false;
    private PaintView paintView;
    public View rootView;
    protected TileDownloadLayer downloadLayer;



protected void createMapViews() {
    mapView = getMapView();
    findViewById(R.id.rotateView).setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mapView.getModel().frameBufferModel.setOverdrawFactor(1.0d);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.getModel().displayModel.setFixedTileSize(256);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mapView.setZoomLevelMin((byte) 10);
    mapView.setZoomLevelMax((byte) 18);

    // create a tile cache of suitable size
    tileCache = AndroidUtil.createTileCache(this, "mapcache", mapView.getModel().displayModel.getTileSize(), 1f, mapView.getModel().frameBufferModel.getOverdrawFactor());

    // tile renderer layer using internal render theme
    tileRendererLayer = new TileRendererLayer(
            tileCache,
            mapDataStore,
            mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition,
            AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE) {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongPress(LatLong tapLatLong, Point thisXY, Point tapXY) {
            CycleProject.this.onLongPress(tapLatLong, tapXY);
            return true;
        }
    };
    tileRendererLayer.setXmlRenderTheme(InternalRenderTheme.DEFAULT);

    // only once a layer is associated with a mapView the rendering starts
    mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(tileRendererLayer);
    mapView.setCenter(MY_INIT_ZOOM_CENTER);
    mapView.setZoomLevel(MY_INIT_ZOOM_LEVEL);

}
```

As I want to use opencycle map as base map which does not offer offline version. Therefore,Online Tile is needed. Wondering if there is any critical difference that it works on tileRender but does not work on TileDownload class please? I have checked and confirm the TileDownloadLayer part works fine on Mapsforge sample "DownloadCustomLayerViewer"

Thanks so much for your advice.